# Saving trainable weights Only - Tensorflow models

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, keras-layer

I want to save the trainable weights of a custom VGG16 model.
I know that : custom_vgg_model.save_weights(fname) => saves all the weights even the untrainable weights of VGG16 .
How can I go and save only the trainable weights?

Answer (score 0):

So generally, you would just save the entire model and then use [`model.load_weights(by_name=True)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#load_weights) to only load weights that you want to transfer. However, if you want to save a subset of the weights for some reason other than transfer (reducing disk space), you could do it like this:

1. Call `layer.get_weights` on the layers which you want to save from your trained model `model1`.
2. Construct a new and smaller VGG model `model2` which has **only** the layers that you want to save (just copy the model declaration from the vgg implementation).
3. Call `layer.set_weights` on all layers of this new `model2` using the weights from `model1` that you have extracted in step 1.
4. Save `model2`.